# how to convert str to int?

Tags: r

I try to input data in R, but I don't know how to convert str into int in following script.

```
>countsTable <- read.table("targets.txt")

>matrixTable <- as.matrix(countsTable)

[1,] "hsa-miR-548ax"      "0"       "1"      
[2,] "hsa-miR-548f"       "0"       "1"      
[3,] "hsa-miR-548g-3p"    "0"       "1"      
[4,] "hsa-miR-5589-3p"    "0"       "1"      
[5,] "hsa-miR-5698"       "0"       "1"      
[6,] "hsa-miR-592"        "0"       "1"      
[7,] "hsa-miR-6129"       "0"       "1"      
[8,] "hsa-miR-658"        "0"       "1" 

> normLimma <- normalizeBetweenArrays(matrixTable,method="quantile")

Error in rowMeans(S) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: Did you do any research before posting? Does as.numeric() not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read.table` returns a data frame (as per the documentation), which is not the same thing as a matrix.

As I'm sure you're aware, your data had three columns, only the second two being numeric. When you convert the data frame from `read.table` to a matrix with `as.matrix` R coerces everything to a single type.

This is because matrices can only hold data from a single type, unlike data frames.

What you probably meant to do was:

```
matrixTable <- as.matrix(countsTable[,-1])
```

to remove the character column.

If you wanted to preserve the first column of data in the matrix, you would probably want to store them as row names:

```
rownames(matrixTable) <- countsTable[,1]
```

Comment: >matrixTable <- as.matrix(sapply(countsTable, as.numeric,header=TRUE))
>rownames(matrixTable) <- countsTable[,1]

Answer (score 2):

Use `as.numeric()`

Quick google search provides some [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/numeric.html)